# Streamlit app works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit, facebook-prophet

I have a stock prediction code using streamlit and fbprophet that is working locally, and when I deploy it on Heroku, it says deployed successfully but on going to the site I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbprophet.plot'
Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 338, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/Stock-Prediction.py", line 8, in <module>
    from fbprophet.plot import plot_plotly
```

I have tried changing fbprophet to prophet but that does not work. Instead of this error, I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet.plot'
```

Even while running the app locally, I was initially getting errors due to fbprophet till I ran it using Anaconda instead of CMD on a Windows system. It works with Anaconda only.
Procfile:

```
web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run Stock-Prediction.py
```

setup.sh:

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/
echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
port = $PORT\n\
enableCORS = false\n\
\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

requirements.txt:

```
streamlit==0.82.0
pandas==1.1.3
yfinance==0.1.59
fbprophet==0.2
plotly==4.14.3
pystan==2.19.1.1
```

While trying to solve this problem I added a packages.txt file containing:

```
gcc
g++
build-essential
python3-dev
```

This is the first time I am trying to deploy an app on Heroku. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use neural prophet instead very easy to install instead of FB prophet

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).